# libsybcs.dll error when installing composer

Tags: installation, composer-php

Running a windows install I keep getting error listed below.

```
"The program can't start because libsybcs.dll is missing from your computer. 
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."
```

Not sure what this means.

Comment: What step in the process do you get this error? What version of windows are you installing? What machine is it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Composer issue, but an PHP or server stack configuration issue.

You enabled the Sybase Extension in your `php.ini`: `php_sybase_ct.dll`.

This DLL requires another DLL to support Sybase, the `libsybcs.dll`.
But this file is missing on your system.

- When you want to work with Sybase, install it correctly, then the DLL is present. Set the folder where the Sybase DLL resides to the ENV path or drop the DLLs into PHPs `ext` folder.
- When you don't need Sybase, disable the PHP extension `php_sybase_ct`.

Then restart PHP and retry the Composer installation.